# how to use get attribute method values to generate drop down in jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

```
public String pincodeDetails(){
        System.out.println("..........................");
        if(shippingAddress.getUserid()==null || usersessionInfo.getUserID() ==null){
            return WebConstant.SESSION_EXPIRED;
        }
        Pincode pincodeObj=null;
        List<Pincode> citLlist=null;
        String stateEnteredcode=null;
        try {
            IAddressMgr iAddressMgr = (IAddressMgr) getBean("iAddressMgr");
            Long pincode=Long.parseLong(txtZip);
            pincodeObj=iAddressMgr.pincodeDetails(pincode);
            stateEnteredcode=pincodeObj.getStateCode();
            citLlist=iAddressMgr.stateWishCities("stateCode", stateEnteredcode);            
            for( Pincode pin:citLlist ){
                System.out.println("Pincode="+pin.getPincode()+", State Name="+pin.getStateName()+", state code"+pin.getStateCode()+", city="+pin.getCityName());
            }
            System.out.println(pincodeObj.getCityName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getServletRequest().setAttribute("pincodedetails", pincodeObj);
        getServletRequest().setAttribute("cities", citLlist);
        return WebConstant.SUCCESS;
```

This is my action code and in jsp I am trying to get the values using the `getAttribute` method and I want to create a drop down list.

Can someone please help me use the values returned by this method in order to create a drop down in jsp?

my jsp code is :

```
    <%@page import="com.bookadda.constant.ApplicationConstant"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%
        if (request.getAttribute("pincodedetails") == null
                || request.getAttribute("cities") == null)
            out.println(request.getAttribute("Invalid Pincode"));
    %>

<%
    if (request.getAttribute("pincodedetails") != null
            || request.getAttribute("cities") != null)
```

Comment: Get the attribute, cast it back to `List<Pincode>` and loop.

Comment: can u please tell me how to create drop down by using these pincodedetails values

Comment: As has already been answered the HTML elements you need are `<select>` for the box and `<option>` for its values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL tag `c:forEach` to generate drop down. Try it in following way

```
<select>
<c:forEach items="${pincodedetails}" var="pincodedetail">  
   <option value="{pincodedetail.pincode}">${pincodedetail.cityName}</option> 
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: tq....ok i will try m fresher and learning now its all new things for me @rahul